# Send message directly using the Index of Node in Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I have a network topology which includes 36 lcn.One of them approximately has 42 sensor nodes in [network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G4KQ.png).After sensing data I want to send data to gcn.To do this, data has to hop lcn to lcn.I did this using the gates.I just forward the packet.However I want to send packet directly to the specified relay node.When I type;

```
 send(packet,"lcnIO$", 7);
```

it normally gives me gate size error because maximum gate size is 8. How can I achieve this.I mean I want to send packet directly to lcn 7 from lcn 0.Both of them have diagonal connection between each others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `send` command can be used to send a message only through **own** gate with given index.
There is no simple way to send a message to one node from vector of nodes selected by index. 
I suggest you to check the index of module at the end of each connection. Moreover, you have to take into account, that the node may not have a connection to the node selected by index. 
Assuming that:

- output gate in `lcn` node is called `out`
- output gate `out` is a vector
- the node wants to send `packet` to the `lcn` node selected by `destIndex`

you can use this piece of `OMNeT++` code:

```
const char * gateName = "out";
int destIndex = 7; // index of destination lcn
cGate *destGate = NULL;
bool found = false;

int i = 0;
int gateSize = gate(gateName, 0)->size();

do {
    destGate = gate(gateName, i++);
    cGate *nextGate = destGate->getNextGate();
    if (nextGate && nextGate->getOwnerModule()->getIndex() == destIndex) {
        found = true;
        send(packet, destGate);
    }
} while (!found && i < gateSize);
// here: found equals to false means that a packet was not sent
```